# Erlang converting proplist to dict

Tags: erlang

I'm new to Erlang and am trying to convert something like the following to a `dict`:

```
{struct,[{<<"1">>,<<"2,3,4">>},{<<"2">>,<<"2,3,4">>}]}
```

I'm getting this after decoding the following json using `mochijson2`:

```
<<"{"1":"2,3,4","2":"2,3,4"}">>
```

The final result I'm looking for would be something like:

```
1 -> [2,3,4]
2 -> [2,3,4]
```

I think it's a proplist but not sure how to proceed with the conversion. Thanks

Comment: Note that mochijson2 can decode directly into a proplist so you needn't do the extra step of matching against `{struct, Result}`: `mochijson2:decode(JSON, [{format, proplist}])`.  The result of this can be passed directly to `dict:from_list/1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking for but this is may be it:

```
1> Term = {struct,[{<<"1">>,<<"2,3,4">>},{<<"2">>,<<"2,3,4">>}]}.                                                                                                             
{struct,[{<<"1">>,<<"2,3,4">>},{<<"2">>,<<"2,3,4">>}]}                                                                                                                        
2> {struct, PropList} = Term.                                                                                                                                                 
{struct,[{<<"1">>,<<"2,3,4">>},{<<"2">>,<<"2,3,4">>}]}                                                                                                                        
3> Dict = dict:from_list(PropList).                                                                                                                                           
{dict,2,16,16,8,80,48,                                                                                                                                                        
      {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},                                                                                                                      
      {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],                                                                                                                                     
        [[<<"2">>|<<"2,3,4">>]],                                                                                                                                              
        [],[],
        [[<<"1">>|<<"2,3,"...>>]],
        []}}}
4> dict:fetch_keys(Dict).
[<<"2">>,<<"1">>]
5> dict:fetch(<<"1">>, Dict).
<<"2,3,4">>
```